# Dump and load of MySQL with correct charset/collation

Tags: mysql, iso-8859-1, character-set

I've a Bamboo build script that shells out to MySQL Admin and does the following:

```
    "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\mysqladmin" -f -h server -u user -p pwd drop db1
    "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\mysqladmin" -f -h server -u user -p pwd create db1
    "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\mysqldump" db2 -h server -r c:\temp\db2.sql -n --no-data -u user -p pwd
    "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\mysql" -h server -D db1 -u user -p pw < c:\temp\db2.sql
```

The code essentially drops the db, recreates it and loads from a default DB (db2)

The problem is that db2 is the following charset/collation

[image: Charset: latin1, Collation: latin1_bin]

Whereas the copied DB is;

[image: Charset: utf8mb4, Collation: utf8mb4_0900_...]

This is creating a problem when our MySQL bulk loader runs and encounters certain characters in the data, such as:

```
    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Invalid utf8mb4 character string: 'TO CHARGE VOLAC '
```

I've spent some time on this site and Google but nothing I've tried has worked.

Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: It looks like you are dumping db1 right after you drop and recreate it.  Is that what you expect?

Comment: Sorry, probably a mistake in my code as I was removing sensitive data.

Answer (score 1):

To answer this, I'm interpreting "default db" as the db you are copying *from* and "copied db" as the new DB you are trying to copy to.

If you create the new database with a SQL command instead of mysqladmin, you can set the character set of the new database:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE db1 CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin;
```

To do from command line:

```
echo 'CREATE DATABASE db1 CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin;' | mysql -h server -u user -ppw
```

(Also, -p with a space after it as in your example won't interpret the password properly, you need to attach it to the -p).